# C - Split a string

Tags: c, string, split

Is there any pre-defined function in C that can split a string given a delimeter? Say I have a string:

```
"Command:Context"
```

Now, I want to store "Command" and "Context" to a two dimensional array of characters

```
char ch[2][10];
```

or to two different variables

```
char ch1[10], ch2[10];
```

I tried using a loop and it works fine. I'm just curious if there is such function that already exists, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Please provide a clear example, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**strtok**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtok.html)

**[Online Demo](http://codepad.org/Da9ixGLP)**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="Command:Context";
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str,":");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ":");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Splitting string "Command:Context" into tokens:
Command
Context
```

Comment: No example in the article. Please guide me :(

Comment: +1 For online demo... Sir, if the string is "Command Context", it's still giving me "Command" and "Context" instead of "Command Context"...

Answer (score 2):

You can tokenise a string with `strtok` as per the following sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char instr[] = "Command:Context";
    char words[2][10];
    char *chptr;
    int idx = 0;

    chptr = strtok (instr, ":");
    while (chptr != NULL) {
        strcpy (words[idx++], chptr);
        chptr = strtok (NULL, ":");
    }

    printf ("Word1 = [%s]\n", words[0]);
    printf ("Word2 = [%s]\n", words[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Word1 = [Command]
Word2 = [Context]
```

The `strtok` function has some minor gotchas that you  probably want to watch out for. Primarily, it modifies the string itself to weave its magic so won't work on string literals (for example).